# teechart for monodroid series cannot trigger click event

Tags: event-handling, xamarin.android, series, teechart

I am using TeeChart for monodroid to create a series which has click event. Please see the code below,

```
newChart.ClickSeries += new Steema.TeeChart.TChart.SeriesEventHandler(mealSeries_ClickSeries);

private void mealSeries_ClickSeries(object sender, Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Series s, int valueIndex, MotionEvent e) 
    {
        DisplayMealDetails(valueIndex);
    }
```

however, this event is never been triggered, I tried to debug, and got this output saying "onTouchEvent: isFocusable: false, isFocusableInTouchMode: false, isFocused: false; focusTaken: false"
so, i added this to my application,

```
newChart.Focusable = true;
newChart.FocusableInTouchMode = true;
```

but still cannot trigger the click event. Anybody could help? thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this has been broken. I have added the issue (TM63016317) to the defect list and will try to fix it for the next maintenance release.

Comment: One more question, I am trying to create a chart with a line series. And this chart will always display the latest 7 values, you are suppose to see the older values when scroll right. Here is the code, newChart.Chart.Zoom.Style = Steema.TeeChart.ZoomStyles.FullChart;
newChart.Panning.Allow = ScrollModes.Horizontal;
newChart.Zoom.Allow = false;  
It seems this ScrollModes.Horizontal is also not working, when I add more then 7 values, it will only show the latest 7 values, the older ones will be cut off from the chart when i scroll right.

Comment: @user1467537 multi-touch zoom & scroll functionality implemented in Mono for Android renders standard TeeChart behaviour non-functional in that field. Therefore I'd expect those properties to not work and should be enhanced for future releases. To achieve what you request you'd probably have to do something as in the All Features\Welcome !\Speed\Realtime charting example in the TeeChart .NET features demo or the so called article at http://www.teechart.net/reference/articles/index.php. The .NET demo can be found with the fully functional eval version at http://www.steema.com/download/net.

Comment: thank you very much! I implemented what I need, except the zoom&scroll part is not working properly. Can I know about when are you going to deploy the next maintenance release?

Comment: @user1467537 What's not working exactly, can you please provide more information? You can send us an example project at http://www.steema.net/upload/ if necessary. Regarding the next maintenance release, a date hasn't been fixed yet but I expect it to be quite soon. Please stay tuned!

Comment: i uploaded a file named yi_chart, please see the latest one. Hope this will be helpful for you. thank you

Comment: @user1467537 In that case you could do something as in this example: http://www.steema.us/files/public/RealTimeTeeChartMfA.zip. Notice this includes a test version of TeeChart.MonoDroid.dll with some new features. If you want to have old points being accessible just don't remove them. However, as I told you before, TeeChart .NET standard scrolling and zooming functionality is not working in Mono for Android. The only solution I can think of is changing bottom axis range (using SetMinMax) to change the points being displayed. If this doesn't help don't hesitate to let me know.

Comment: @user1467537 as an update, a new maintenance release fixing the ClickSeries issue and improving the real-time performance has just ben published: http://www.steema.com/entry/137/TeeChart_Mono_for_Android_4.0.2012.121203_maintenance_release_available